# Enable extended database information if data is private to executing user

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

Right now, the `UserId` for `Votes` [is only available if the vote is a favorite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/160410). It would be nice if users logged in could have `UserId` for all types of votes that they themselves cast, so queries for closeness to the Sportsmanship badge, for example, could be implemented.

Comment: If you really wanted this, you could parse the results given to you at `sitename.stackexchange.com/reputation` and get your votes from there.  It's just a matter of the parsing which shouldn't be too difficult. Of course you're not going to get everything I suppose (e.g., bounties, suggested edits(?), etc.).

Comment: *Related:* Viewing your own votes through the API has been [requested](http://stackapps.com/a/2613/4112) [twice](http://stackapps.com/questions/2850/2-0-api-get-votes) on Stack Apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm not horribly mistaken, SEDE's data source is the [publicly available data dump](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/), where votes are anonymized. Obviously that can't change for the data dump, so the only way for such a feature to get implemented would be for SEDE to have a different data source. I think we can safely assume that SEDE will never be tied to live data, so a different data source would mean yet another data dump the team would have to maintain.

Too much trouble just to check your badge progress, don't you think?

Comment: The bit about where the data comes from isn't strictly true, but implementing this functionality would be nevertheless be extremely problematic.

Comment: Good point. Anyway, it turns out I did get the badge, I just didn't wait long enough to find out :)